# How to use appropriate regex to find a pattern in sed?

Tags: linux, text-processing, command-line, sed

I have a file containing a set of information as below:

```
cat filename
    1   S121
    2   M121
    3   MS121
    4   SM154
    5   SM91
```

I am trying to change only all of those which has `[mM] to MS` plus keeping the same pattern. The following `sed script` was tried

```
sed -r 's/ms?([0-9])/MS\1/Ig' filename
```

but it is not specific only to [mM] and can change the lines 4 and 5 as in the output as below:

```
4       SMS154
5       SMS91
```

any help is appreciated. tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching a substring, starting with *"m"*, *optionally* followed by *"s"*, and then followed by a digit *[0-9]*.

The text on lines 4,5 does contain this substring too:

4   S**M1**54

5   S**M9**1

so they are replaced.

Try prefixing your pattern with *"\s"* to indicate that you are only interested in the prefix of column #2, like that:

```
sed -r 's/(\s)ms?([0-9])/\1XX\2/Ig'
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me more about the prefixing with "\s" ? ! read that the \s mean space [[:space:]].  Is prefixing "\s" something new in regex. how/where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Sure, that is pretty easy actually, "\s" stands for a whitespace, so if you write "\sms?", this will only match the beginning of the string in column #2, but not the substring further inside the column text.

Comment: @zppelin But what if in case there would a number  before the "ms" let's say 123ms62890. This script then would not work there. DO you have any alternative please :)

Comment: You can use a character range to match digit or whitespace,  e.g. [0-9\s], instead of just whitespace,  then.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one ?
is it correct for your question ?

```
sed -r 's/m([^s])/MS\1/Ig' file
```